# View stderr from c-library, Debian Linux

Tags: c, linux, debugging, file-descriptor, stderr

I'm very new to linux programming, and is just learning my ways around the OS. I have made an application, but it isn't working as intended to. I'm using a [library](https://github.com/beagleboard/am335x_pru_package/blob/master/pru_sw/app_loader/interface/prussdrv.c), to enable some functionalities. In the source code of the library, I see that a macro is defined:

```
#ifdef __DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(FORMAT, ...) fprintf(stderr, FORMAT, ## __VA_ARGS__)
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINTF(FORMAT, ...)
#endif
```

**I want to see the messages send *DEBUG_PRINTF*, so I guess I'll need a way to view the *stderr*..** I have no clue about how to do this. I've reasearched a bit, but can't seem to access the filedescriptor of the application.

I'm using a BeagleBone Black, running a Debian Distribution "Linux beaglebone 3.8.13-bone47"

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: add in you code the line #define __DEBUG

Comment: Ahh, okay, I did that, but i still don't know how to actually read the stderr..

Comment: Try to run the executable in this way: ./executable >> /home/user/stdout_and_error.log  2>&1.

This will log both stdout and stderr to a file.

Comment: Btw, if that library is a shared one, try to recompile with __DEBUG defined.

Answer (score 1):

`stderr` is not an application, it is just another output stream on the console, just like `stdout`. The main differences are that `stderr` is not (usually) buffered and is not redirected by default if you pipe your program's output somewhere. For instance if you type:

`program > file.txt`

Your programs output on `stdout` stream would be redirected to `file.txt` but anything printed on the `stderr` stream will still be displayed on the console and not written to the file. (As 23ars suggests in the comments, the way to redirect stderr as well is to use `2>&1` which redirects `stderr` to `stdout`).

You don't need to do anything differently to read `stderr` than you do to read `stdout`. It should just appear on the console. `printf` by default outputs to `stdout` which is why you have to use `fprintf` as this allows you to specify a different output stream - `stderr`.

---

Example:

Try the following simple hello world program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    printf("I am printed on stdout\n");
    fprintf(stderr, "I am printed on stderr\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Compile and run this and you should see:

```
I am printed on stdout
I am printed on stderr
```

Now run this but pipe to a file:
`program > file.txt`
and you should now only see:

```
I am printed on stderr
```

appear on your console.
If you inspect `file.txt` you should only see

```
I am printed on stdout
```

Finally you can try `program > file.txt 2>&1`
and you should see nothing printed on the console, but inspecting the file should reveal both lines have been sent there.

I hope this clears it up a bit :).